# why gcc don't optimize coroutine in c++?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20, c++-coroutine

I have tried an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/4KKTPhEEc) (it is copied from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/noop_coroutine), so it should be right.) about c++20 coroutines. The example is very simple, and I turned on -O3 optimization, but gcc did not optimize it into the best assembly code. (I think in the best assembly code, the main function should be empty because the main function has not done any meaningful thing in fact.)
My question is:

1. does the main function can be optimized into empty? (Will not against the standard if we do that.)
2. if 1 is true, why gcc cannot optimize it? Is there any way that can optimize the main function to empty or gcc just cannot do that at current?

The example code is below:

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <utility>
 
template<class T>
struct task
{
    struct promise_type
    {
        auto get_return_object()
        {
            return task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this));
        }
        std::suspend_always initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        struct final_awaiter
        {
            bool await_ready() noexcept { return false; }
            void await_resume() noexcept {}
            std::coroutine_handle<>
                await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h) noexcept
            {
                // final_awaiter::await_suspend is called when the execution of the
                // current coroutine (referred to by 'h') is about to finish.
                // If the current coroutine was resumed by another coroutine via
                // co_await get_task(), a handle to that coroutine has been stored
                // as h.promise().previous. In that case, return the handle to resume
                // the previous coroutine.
                // Otherwise, return noop_coroutine(), whose resumption does nothing.
 
                if (auto previous = h.promise().previous; previous)
                    return previous;
                else
                    return std::noop_coroutine();
            }
        };
        final_awaiter final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void unhandled_exception() { throw; }
        void return_value(T value) { result = std::move(value); }
 
        T result;
        std::coroutine_handle<> previous;
    };
 
    task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h) : coro(h) {}
    task(task&& t) = delete;
    ~task() { coro.destroy(); }
 
    struct awaiter
    {
        bool await_ready() { return false; }
        T await_resume() { return std::move(coro.promise().result); }
        auto await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h)
        {
            coro.promise().previous = h;
            return coro;
        }
        std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> coro;
    };
    awaiter operator co_await() { return awaiter{coro}; }
    T operator()()
    {
        coro.resume();
        return std::move(coro.promise().result);
    }
 
private:
    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> coro;
};
 
task<int> get_random()
{
    co_return 4;
}
 
task<int> test()
{
    task<int> v = get_random();
    task<int> u = get_random();
    int x = (co_await v + co_await u);
    co_return x;
}
 
int main()
{
    task<int> t = test();
    int result = t();
}
```

Comment: You can copy the code in the question.

Comment: updated, you can see the code in the example link, too. @kiner_shah

Comment: Compilers are always allowed to optimize away anything that doesn't have observable side effects. But "allowed" is *not* "guaranteed to".

Comment: I almost find why. When we use co_return, the coroutine is not destroyed, so the operator delete is not called in time.